# How could i use a variable created within JavaScript to set the "src" attribute of an image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a very simple web page that rotates 3 Pre-existing images throughout the day depending on the time on the users computer. I have managed to set up if statements that can check for the time of the day and execute an action via an if statement based on what time of the day it is (this functionality works as intended), however i am struggling to do what i have mentioned in the title of this question..

Below is the HTML code i have for the image, this lies above the script tag, therefore the image is already created before the javascript executes.

```
<img id="dayImage" src="" alt="Unable to load image" />
```

Hereafter, is the internal javascript i have which carries out this particular function:

```
<script>

            var image = document.getElementById('dayImage');

            var myDate = new Date();
            var hrs = myDate.getHours();

            if (hrs < 12)
                image.setAttribute("src", "~/Images/Morning.PNG");

            else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
                image.setAttribute("src", "~/Images/Noon.PNG");

            else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
                image.setAttribute("src", "~/Images/Evening.PNG");

        </script>
```

I am doing this within an ASP.NET MVC project file, if that is of any help. Im unsure as to if i am missing something very obvious here... any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: the code is fine, looks like you may not have the right path to your images

Comment: After loading the page, what's the `src` value you're getting? Can you check if it's the correct path?

Comment: I also think the code is correct. Please check file paths. For that hard code file path and check.

Comment: So when i run the HTML on its own, by taking the image Id out, and using the same path as in the javascript code, the images display just fine.

Comment: you seem to be missing curly brackets around your if clauses?

Comment: For example if i just run this; `<img  src="~/Images/Evening.PNG" alt="Unable to load image" />` the web page will display the image

Comment: @RachelGallen that's a shorthand way of running if/else. You don't need curly brackets if you have a single line to execute.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I suppose. I just always put them in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `"~/"` to the script might refer to a relative path where the view is stored. Using `Url.Content(path)` starts from the web root and will give the absolute url of the file in the server.

```
if (hrs < 12)
   image.setAttribute('src', '@Url.Content("~/Images/Morning.PNG")');
else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
   image.setAttribute('src', '@Url.Content("~/Images/Noon.PNG")');
else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
   image.setAttribute('src', '@Url.Content("~/Images/Evening.PNG")');
```

EDIT: change to single quote

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk you're welcome. Good luck with the project.